# compile coffescript and stylus in jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, gulp, stylus

i'm using gulp and i have a question:

is there any way to write coffescript and stylus inside the jade-files with *script* and *style* tags to compile them to three difference files (html, css and js)?

for example, i want to write something like this:

```
h1.foo#bar hello, world!

style
  .foo
    color $stylusVariable

script
  $('#bar').click ->
    console.log $(this)
```

and get index.html and app.js and style.css (which contain all the js and css code from the project). can u help me with needful plugins and gulp-task?

Comment: http://jade-lang.com/reference/filters/

Answer (score 0):

You should checking jade version on your machine and reread jade document. Jade support to writer js in jade files now.

http://jade-lang.com/reference/filters/

Comment: thank you for your answer, but what about stylus inside jade?